# How to set attribute "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" with ellipsis using antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd, typography, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I need to show comment with ellipsis. I have used antd's Paragraph Typography for it.
My problem is that comment can also contain html attributes (link to tagged users) so I also need to set **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** in the component. How to set this in Typography component?

```
<Paragraph ellipsis={{ rows: 2, expandable: true, symbol: "more" }}>
      {comment}
</Paragraph>
```

**Preview:**
[image]

I tried using span inside Paragraph to use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**, but then ellipsis started showing just "...more" for all long comments, without showing any initial characters in the comment to fill the width. Also getting a warning on using any HTML element inside `<Paragraph></Paragragh>` other than string

```
<Paragraph ellipsis={{ rows: 2, expandable: true, symbol: "more" }}>
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: comment.comment }} />
</Paragraph>
```

**Preview:**
[image]

**Warning:**
[image]

Any workaround for achieving this??

Comment: did you try to change the span to a div?: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'This text is set using dangerouslySetInnerHTML'}}>

Comment: you can check a pretty good review on this link:  https://medium.com/better-programming/what-is-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-6d6a98cbc187  use incognito mode

Comment: @crizcl, Same issue with div as well.

Comment: Actually I'm also getting this warning on using any HTML element inside <Paragraph></Paragragh> other than string -
Warning: [antd: Typography] `ellipsis` should use string as children only.

Comment: what is the ellipsis library you are using? can you share the link? what version of antd?

Comment: Antd - 4.7.2
https://ant.design/components/typography/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I would love this functionality for antd Typography as well but that is not the case at the moment so here is a bit of a work around for you in the meantime.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "antd/es/button";

import ChopLines from "chop-lines";
import insane from "insane";

const Sanitized = ({ html }) => (
    <div
        className={styles.sanitizedBody}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: insane(html, {
                allowedTags: [
                    "p",
                    "strong",
                    "em",
                    "a",
                    "b",
                    "i",
                    "span",
                    "div",
                    "br",
                    "u",
                    "img",
                ],
            }),
        }}
    />
);

const Ellipsis = ({ expand }) => (
    <Button
        size="small"
        shape="round"
        type="primary"
        onClick={expand}
    >
        ...see more
    </Button>
);

const Post = ({content}) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

    render (
        <div>
            {expanded ? (
                <Sanitized html={content} />
            ) : (
                <ChopLines
                    maxHeight={90}
                    ellipsis={
                        <Ellipsis expand={expand}>
                            <span>Read More</span>
                        </Ellipsis>
                    }
                >
                    <Sanitized html={content} />
                </ChopLines>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't do it in antd now.
How about [react-truncate-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-truncate-html)

Ex:

```
import Truncate from 'react-truncate-html';
 
<Truncate
  lines={3}
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
   __html: "Hi, <strong>here’s some</strong> <i>HTML</i>"
  }}
/>
```

> I have no idea how to make custom ellipsis text, button, ... (ex: read more)